# How do I get possible combinations of a list within a specific range in Python?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have this list:

```
letters = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ')
```

How can I get possible combinations of this list within a range of only 4 characters?

So my result set would be, for example:

- ABC
- NIJK
- C
- FK
- QACD
- ....

I tried it like this, but this does not seem to work:

```
for L in range(0, 4):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(letters, L):
        word = ''.join(subset)
        print(word)
```

Comment: "within a range of only 4 characters". Do you mean all possible subsets of this string with at most 4 characters?

Comment: Could you expand on *"does not seem to work"*?

Comment: Exactly, I want all possible subsets but they should be at most 4 characters. At the moment, I also get strings with more than 4 characters.

Comment: The code you're showing won't produce strings longer than 3 characters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to count from 1 to 4, not from 0 to 3:

```
result = []
for L in range(1, 5):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(letters, L):
        result.append(''.join(subset))
```